# Emails from VPS going to Spam folder

Tags: email, vps, spam

i'm using unmanaged VPS from Contabo, i don't know why my emails are going to Spam folder, i checked many articles, i set SPF record but the same problem, any idea?

```
    Delivered-To: r_haceb@esi.dz
Received: by 10.140.28.98 with SMTP id 89csp63344qgy;
        Sun, 6 Apr 2014 13:02:57 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.229.230.68 with SMTP id jl4mr29009103qcb.2.1396814577669;
        Sun, 06 Apr 2014 13:02:57 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <contact@printdz.com>
Received: from vmi19458 (ip-30-185-143-79.static.contabo.net. [79.143.185.30])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id m6si5836502qay.218.2014.04.06.13.02.53
        for <r_haceb@esi.dz>
        (version=TLSv1.2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 06 Apr 2014 13:02:57 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 79.143.185.30 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of contact@printdz.com) client-ip=79.143.185.30;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=neutral (google.com: 79.143.185.30 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of contact@printdz.com) smtp.mail=contact@printdz.com;
       dkim=neutral (no key for signature) header.i=@printdz.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=printdz.com; s=default;
    h=Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Subject:Message-ID:Date:To:From; bh=vEH0oxcAnuvem9JO5KMEXGGPvJrXQ46uir2TfFo6T0U=;
    b=SnGkZAXRW9gO1IY3TP4v3QJ7gHArhtjIJN/sOCk2sOf0i/jLDNLNneZ8xaU2s/oV4OEzmETVPqJ2wFk5g1WDG9e8R27sKfzbwXj8R6H5UmvLgecJ/W7nJZRNeBYOxB6HJx4BkXoi4KaYFR2FYekufmfGWhExo/nPRPJyelzkvg4=;
Received: from ip-30-185-143-79.static.contabo.net ([79.143.185.30]:46956 helo=www.printdz.com)
    by vmi19458 with esmtpa (Exim 4.82)
    (envelope-from <contact@printdz.com>)
    id 1WWtHI-0000ie-Gv
    for r_haceb@esi.dz; Sun, 06 Apr 2014 22:02:52 +0200
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Note that your SPF is not configured or this line wouldn't appear

> Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 79.143.185.30 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of contact@printdz.com) client-ip=79.143.185.30;

To confirm that your SPF is not ok, go here http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

The solution would be asking Contabo to fix your DNS record regarding SPF.